# Split CSV data in biweekly partitions

Tags: python, date, csv

I'm running into problems due to my lack of experience with python while studying climate Data. I have a rather large CSV file (original data in NetCDF4 format) with multiple columns (Latitude, Longtitude, Concentration of Ammonia and Date (in YYYY-MM-DD hour-min-sec format)). This is point data measured by sattelite equipment.

However, for analysis I would like to split this CSV file into Biweekly format to use in Arcgis (so 2 csv files per month, 1-15 and 16-end). I can do this manually, but doing this for multiple years would be very inefficient by hand.

Any pointers towards the right directions or tips are very welcome.

Thank you,

Comment: Is the input data sorted by Date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help:

```
import csv
import datetime
import sys
import os.path


def key(date):
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    date = datetime.date(date.year,
                         date.month,
                         1 if date.day < 16 else 16)
    date = date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    return date

old_key = None
for filename in sys.argv[1:]:
    with open(filename) as file_in:
        base, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
        rows_in = csv.reader(file_in)
        for row in rows_in:
            new_key = key(row[3])
            if new_key != old_key:
                old_key = new_key
                filename_out = '%s-%s%s'%(base, new_key, ext)
                file_out = open(filename_out, 'w')
                rows_out = csv.writer(file_out)
            rows_out.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd write a short script like:

```
out_file_idx = 0
def open_next_file(): return open('splitdata_%s.csv' % out_file_idx, 'w')
out_file = open_next_file()
for line in open('mydata.csv'):
    date = line.split(',')[-1]  # last cell in CSV is date as you mentioned
    if current_day_is_15_and_previous_day_is_not_15()
        or current_day_is_1_and_previous_day_is_not_1():
        out_file.close()
        out_file_idx += 1
        out_file = open_next_file()
    out_file.write(line)
    out_file.write('\n')
```

Of course you have to implement these two functions in the conditional statement and actually use the `date` variable. Hope it helps!